# Any homomorphism from a group to its covering group has a complement.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then another group $K$ is called a covering group of $G$ if there exists a subgroup $L$ of $[K, K]\cap Z(K)$ such that $\frac{K}{L} \cong G$ and $L\cong M(G)$, where $M(G)$ is the Schur multiplier of $G$. I am studying the article [Isoclinisms and covering groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9A7852B63C878015C28E0AE19C72FFAF/S0004972700043653a.pdf/isoclinisms-and-covering-groups.pdf). If $G$ has a free presentation $$1\longrightarrow R \longrightarrow F \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow 1$$
taking $H=\frac{F}{[R,F]}$, $I=\frac{R}{[R,F]}$ and $T=\frac{[F,F]\cap R}{[R,F]}$. The author says that "if $L$ is any covering group for $G$, there is an epimorphism $\phi$ from $H$ onto $L$ such that ker$\phi$ is a complement for T in I. They reference an article by I. Schur, which is in German language. Is there any idea to prove this?

Comment: It is not easy to help you with this, because you have not said which article you are reading, and you have not provided the reference to the article by Schur. An immediate problem is that your definition of a covering group is not correct for general groups because when , for example, $G$ is a countably infinite elementary abelian group, $M(G)$ has proper quotients that are isomorphic to itself. Are you perhaps assuming that $G$ is finite - or at least finitely generated?

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for your comment. The group is finite and I have also provided the link to the reference article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of the argument. You will have to fill in the details yourself.

The homomorphism $F \to H$ lifts to a homomorphism $\phi: F \to K$ with $\phi(R) \le L$.

Since $L \le Z(K)$, we have $[F,R] \le \ker \phi$, so $\phi$ induces $\bar{\phi}:H \to K$ with $\bar{\phi}(I) \le L$.

Since $L \le [K,K]$, we have  $\bar{\phi}(T) = L$. But we are assuming that $L \cong M(G)$ and we know fro the Hopf formula that $T \cong M(G)$ so, since we are assuming that $G$ and hence also $M(G)$ is finite, $\bar{\phi}:T \to L$ is an isomorphism.

So $\ker \bar{\phi}$ is a complement to $T$ in $I$. Note also that, since it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $F/[F,F]$, which is free abelian, this complement is also free abelian.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.